# What does this solidity code do in crowdsale contract?

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

Trying to level up on my solidity skills. I understand most of the crowdsale contract except these lines

```
balances[teamWallet] = 3000 ether;
        emit Transfer(address(0x0), teamWallet, (3000 ether));
        frozenBalances[teamWallet] = 3000 ether;
        timelock[teamWallet] = teamReleaseTime;
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you about each one of these lines in terms of solidity???

Comment: what does "balances[teamWallet] =3000 ether;" mean? Does it mean when the account reaches 3000 ether that it does not accept more?

Comment: It means that in the `balances` mapping, you map the key `teamWallet` to the value `3000e18` (which is the integer 3 followed by 21 zeros).

Comment: I guess I am confused on how one can map an Ether value... What does the mapping represent?

Comment: The keyword `ether` only means that the number which precedes it is multiplied by `10 ** 18`.

Comment: Oky thank you. Then lastly, why would they assign a mapping a value...what does that do?

Comment: Why would you assign a value to a variable?

Comment: To calculate something lul?

Comment: So obviously for the same reason.